# HDMI audio on default alsa device in xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, hdmi, alsa

My new monitor (Asus MX279) have 2 speakers and audio input from HDMI.
In xubuntu 12.10 it doesn't work by default.

I identified the correct device with `aplay -l`
and sound works great with

```
speaker-test -c wav -D plughw:1,7
```

and

```
aplay -D plughw:1,7 myTest.wav
```

Now, how can i set this device (in this case card 1, device 7) as default audio device?
I've tried creating `~/.asoundrc` like this:

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 1
    device 7
}
```

and restarting alsa with `sudo alsa reload`, or rebooting system but it did not work.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

I've created file `/etc/asound.conf` in this way:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 7
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

and rebooted the system.

remember: in my case "1" is the card number and "7" is device number found in `aplay -l` output.

Case. Closed.

See ya!